# Duplicate styles with react-rails and react-jss server-side rendering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, server-side-rendering, jss

I'm working in an application with React on the frontend and RubyOnRails on the backend.

I'm using `react-rails` the render the views and `react-jss` for styling. I recently started trying to implement server-side rendering but I've been having some problems with the style.

I render my view using the following react-rails helper:

```
<%= react_component("Header", {}, { prerender: true }) %>
```

And my component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import injectSheet, { JssProvider, SheetsRegistry } from 'react-jss';

const Header = ({ classes }) => {

  return (
    <JssProvider generateClassName={createGenerateClassName()} registry={sheets}>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        // component
      </div>
    </JssProvider>
  );
}

const style = {
  // style
};

const HeaderWithStyle = injectSheet(style)(Header); 

export default () => {

  const sheets = new SheetsRegistry();

  return (
    <JssProvider registry={sheets}>
      <HeaderWithStyle />
    </JssProvider>
  )

};
```

When I open it in the browser I get the following warning message and the styles aren't at all applied.

> Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "SearchBar-search-0-1-2 SearchBar-search-0-1-3" Client: "SearchBar-search-2-1-2 SearchBar-search-2-1-3"

When looking at the source code I can see that not only the the className won't match, but the sheets itself won't match. So it looks like the browser preserves the HTML generated in the backend, but in the client `react-jss` re-generates the stylesheets using new names and someway overrides the previous.

[image]

[image]

I have seen [this example](https://github.com/cssinjs/examples/tree/gh-pages/react-ssr) but it injects the body and stylesheets directly in the htmç and since I'm using Rails it would need a major refactor to make it work like this.

Does anyway a have a clue how to make it work using RubyOnRails?